# Divs and textboxes in html

Tags: html, css

[image: Creating user interfaces]

I am currently working on creating user interfaces. I came across this picture and was inspired. I know this may not be the place to ask but i need to to know. I know how to to the textboxes and dropdown menu. I am interested on how i can add the 'Manage users' and 'Show Provenance' shown in black in the left at those positions exactly as well as creating the gap between the 'contract information', 'Credentials' and 'Manage Users' and aligning the words in that manner. Please send a code snippet. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may want to use a framework like Semantic UI: https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html

Comment: This is not a free coding service, this is a site for where you have attempted your own code and got stuck with a particular problem.  As it stands, this question is too broad and therefore off topic for SO

Answer (score 0):

Check out Bootstrap4 and the input group options:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/input-group/

You can probably use emoticons aswell for additional graphics options.